# Integer solutions to equation with surds

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Are there any integer solutions to the equation $a \sqrt 2 + b = c \sqrt 3$? I don't think there are, because squaring each sides implies that $2ab \sqrt 2$ is an integer, which is impossible if $a$ and $b$ are. However, I want to be sure.

Comment: what about $a=b=c=0$? (Show that it is actually the only integer solution)

Comment: @OussamaBoussif you ninja'd me to it!

Comment: @PatrickStevens haha xD well it all depends on speed ^^

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557976/show-that-1-sqrt2-sqrt3-is-linearly-independent-over-mathbbq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is required for $a$ or $b$ to be zero. If $b = 0$ we get by squaring that $2a^2 = 3c^2$, which is a contradiction because the power of 2 is odd on the LHS and even on the RHS, unless $a=c=0$.

If $a=0$ then we get $b = c \sqrt{3}$, which by squaring is a contradiction with the power of 3 on each side, unless $b=c=0$.

Therefore, $a=b=c=0$ is the only solution in integers.