# Can all irrational numbers be written in the form $u + v\sqrt{2}$, with $u$ and $v$ rational?

Tags: complex-numbers, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I am curious to know whether all irrational numbers can be written in the form $u + v\sqrt{2}$, with $u$ and $v$ rational.

(Almost similar to how all complex numbers can be written as $x + iy$, with $x$ and $y$ real.)

Comment: $\sqrt{3}$ cannot

Comment: Uh, no? How are you going to write $\sqrt{3} = u + v\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: The set $\{u+v\sqrt 2~|~u,v\in \mathbb Q\}$ is countable, while $\mathbb R$ is not. Thus, no.

Comment: Not even integers can be written so !

Comment: $u+v\sqrt2$ is algebraic ($(x-u)^2-2v^2=0$) and cannot represent any transcendental number.

Comment: This question should have more upvotes

Comment: @YvesDaoust: "Not even integers...": Yes they can. $n = n + 0\sqrt 2$.

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas Why? For not showing any effort to solve the problem?

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas So what's stopping you? :) It had a downvote (which I canceled), but it has 4 (!) votes to close.

Comment: @BrianO I upvoted.

Comment: @Aniket maybe someone with 11 rep cannot make an effort to solve the problem and needs help.It was a nice question

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas Good. Voting so far: +3/-3.

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas First of all. rep is not a measure of anybody's knowledge. Secondly, even if "someone with 11 rep" needs real help, OP must have thought something after which progress could not be made. It is expected that the question will contain this effort. The minimum effort at least...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another reason that not all irrationals can be written as $u+v\sqrt 2$ with $u,v\in \Bbb Q$: there are only countably many reals of that form, but the irrationals are uncountable.

Answer (score 7):

Let $\sqrt3=u+v\sqrt2$. Then by squaring, $3=u^2+2\sqrt2uv+2v^2$ and $\sqrt2=\dfrac{3-u^2-2v^2}{2uv}$ is a rational number !?

Comment: And if $u=0$? :)

Comment: @BrianO: you know the answer :)

Comment: I do, I confess. In that case, $\frac 3 2 = v^2$, but $3,2$ are square-free, relatively prime... problems with that. I mentioned it more for OP, and  future readers.

Comment: A separate post about this: [Show that $\{1, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}\}$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557976/show-that-1-sqrt2-sqrt3-is-linearly-independent-over-mathbbq)

Answer (score 0):

No.

Counterexample: $$\forall u,v \in \mathbb{Q}, \, \sqrt{3} \neq u + v\sqrt{2}.$$

Answer (score -1):

No. It is not possible.  For examples,

$$\pi, e, e^\pi, \pi^e$$