# Proof if p is prime$f: \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (a,b) \mapsto a+b \sqrt{p}$ then $f$ is not surjective

Tags: functions

> Prove that if $p$ is prime, then $f: \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (a,b) \mapsto a+b \sqrt{p}$ is not surjective.

In general surjective proofs I normally take an output and prove that it can be achieved by a certain input.

Now, to prove that $f$ it is not surjective, **can I take a specific output** and prove that it doesn't have an input like this?:

$\varphi + \pi \sqrt{p}$

$\mathbb{Q}\ni a = \varphi \in \mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{Q}$

and

$\mathbb{Q}\ni b = \pi\in \mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{Q}$

which are both contradictions.

Comment: Note that there is _no_ surjective function $\Bbb Q\times \Bbb Q \to \Bbb R$. There are just too many real numbers.

Comment: You (counter)example doesn't work, since $f$ is only defined on rationals, so  $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$. You could try to find $a,b$ such as $f(a,b)=0$ instead.

Comment: @dxiv but The example-output is in $\mathbb{R}$, so it must be a valid output, right?

Comment: You did *not* prove that there exist no $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $a+b\sqrt{p}=\varphi+\pi \sqrt{p}$.

Comment: @dvix, I guess you are right, im still wondering how I could prove it by counterexample, additionally to the correct solution of sigmabe

Comment: For an explicit counterexample (as opposed to a proof by cardinality) take a different prime $q \ne p$ and prove that $f(a,b)=\sqrt{q}$ has no solutions for $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$. The proof would work out similarly to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557976/show-that-1-sqrt2-sqrt3-is-linearly-independent-over-mathbbq).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can't be surjective, because
$$|\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}|=|\mathbb{N}|<|\mathbb{R}|$$
and so there's **no surjective function** $f\colon \mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}$.